# Why app not launching on booting android device installed in external sd card?

Tags: android

I have a tracker app which i want to run on boot up of the device. It works fine if it is installed in the internal storage but when the users move it to their sd card, my app won't work during boot up, they need to move it due to shortage in internal storage capacity. Any suggestions please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have permission to the sd card? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4246141/295004

Comment: @NvMat: yes i have stated the permissions in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is provided in Android's [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) doc.

Quote:

> The system delivers the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast before the
>   external storage is mounted to the device. If your application is
>   installed on the external storage, it can never receive this
>   broadcast.

[EDIT]

If your app is not that big but users are running out of internal storage because your app is storing too much data, you could have your app [write that data to external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). In this case, you should make your app [installable only in internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) (since it has to receive `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`).

Comment: i see. thanks for the answer @cybersam. Would there be any work around with this problem?

Comment: I have added a possible workaround to my answer, but it may not apply to your case.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Well, as I had checked, the device itself has a very low storage capacity and the users want it to be installed in their external sd card. As you've already mentioned, it might not work well with that workaround.